# Why Doesn't Mathematica Evaluate This Integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am using Mathematica (the online version, but not WolframAlpha) and I'm trying to estimate the integral $\int_{-1}^1 e^{\frac{i}{1+x^2}}\,dx$. To do so, I've entered: `NIntegrate[E^[I/[1 + x^2]], {x, -1, 1}]`.

However, instead of returning a number it just returns the integral I wrote above. Meanwhile, WolframAlpha estimates this just fine, as in https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+e%5E%28i%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29%29%2C+x%3D-1..1

As a follow up (I'm new to Mathematica) if I'm interested in estimating integrals, is there a way to do it that is quicker?

Comment: `NIntegrate[E^(I/(1 + x^2)), {x, -1, 1}]`

Comment: @cvgmt If you are suggesting an edit, it returns the same thing either way.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: what @MichaelE2 means -I think- is that you should take a closer look to the comment above. see the differences between brackets and parentheses for instance

Comment: You're right.  My eyes are not very good.  Your code has a syntax error which @cvgmt corrects.

Comment: @bmf I copied and pasted exactly what cvgmt wrote and it returned the exact same thing as what I wrote, ie. it just returned the integral but no value

Comment: @MichaelE2 There may be a syntax error however it doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: this is what @cvgmt suggested; see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5617.png)

Comment: @bmf I tried exactly that and it didn't work, see this image: https://ibb.co/Z6np22z ...is it possible the online version doesn't work properly?

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. In the sense, I am not sure if it's an issue of the online version or the free version

Comment: @JLA You need to use the new line. The old one uses = in the start.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников I'm not sure if I understand what you mean but this doesn't seem like the problem because what I wrote works for other integrals.

Comment: @JLA But not for this one.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников Sorry, what are you suggesting I do? Not write an = sign?

Comment: Press Enter to get a new line and then do not press =.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников Ok thank you, that did kind of work but for the integral I want it seems to be giving an answer, but an incorrect one. But for this question it is resolved.

Comment: Solution of this integral we can write as infinty series :$$\int_{-1}^1 \exp \left(\frac{i}{1+x^2}\right) \, dx=\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{2 (-i)^{-j} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},j;\frac{3}{2};-1\right)}{j!}$$

Answer (score 2):

Clear["Global`*"]

Starting an input with `=` requests "complete computation using natural language" which doesn't work in this case
[image]

Eliminate the leading `=` and `Mathematica` works as expected

```
NIntegrate[E^(I/(1 + x^2)), {x, -1, 1}]

(* 1.3958 + 1.3962 I *)
```

Or using `WolframAlpha` from within `Mathematica`

```
WolframAlpha["NIntegrate[E^(I/(1+x^2)), {x, -1, 1}]"]
```

[image]